# Can't get UITapGestureRecognizer to recognize specific views in controller

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a menu controller that when it pops up has a collection view. The way it works is that when the user taps outside the collection view it should make the menu dismiss. The menu dismisses when you tap outside the collection view, but it also dismisses when you tap inside the collection view. I can't seem to get the gesture recognizer to only dismiss when it is not inside the collection view. I have looked around on here and google and I haven't found any solution yet that works. Here is the code for the function that handles the tap:

```
    @IBAction func handleTap(sender: MenuTapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (sender.state == .Ended && sender.view == menuCollectionView)
        {
            NSLog("menuCollectionView")
        }
        else if (sender.state == .Ended && sender.view == mainView)
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

`mainView` is a reference that is connected to the top most view and `menuCollectionView` is the reference to the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have only attached the gesture recognizer to your `mainView`. This is fine, but you will want to use `sender.locationInView(menuCollectionView)` and check to see if the point is within the bounds of your collection view. This is done with the following:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(menuCollectionView.bounds, sender.locationInView(menuCollectionView))) {
  // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: I tried using that to make a check and I keep getting that 'CGPoint is not convertible to ObjC Bool' I am assuming I am checking this incorrectly then

Comment: `sender.locationInView(menuCollectionView)` will return a `CGPoint` that marks the location of your event within `menuCollectionView`. You can use `CGRectContainsPoint(menuCollectionView.bounds, sender.locationInView(menuCollectionView))`.

Comment: Thank you Ian that worked perfectly! I used the CGRectContainsPoint and it filtered directly to the collection view. :) been stuck on that for two weeks, thanks!